# Convert mysql response from VM into specific format

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, sed, mysql

Using a shell job I am getting a response from mysql in below text format,

[image: response from mysql on vm]

**In a text way as requested**

+-------+

|    A    |

+-------+

|   36   |

+-------+

+-------+

|    B    |

+-------+

|   57   |

+-------+

+-------+

|    C    |

+-------+

|   11   |

+-------+

or a response like

**A**

**36**

**B**

**57**

**C**

**11**

I want to be able to transform the data into simple way as text file like below:

**A 36**

**B 57**

**C 11**

https://justpaste.it/edit/30310895/df1838c844c0fcd1

Comment: What's the `mysql` command? Probably makes more sense to stop it from producing 'pretty tables' than sorting out this mess later

Comment: It will be fine if we can get this transform without pretty tables, I'll update the question- its a simple query

Comment: Is your input numbers inside boxes as in your first example or just a list of numbers (much easier to parse) as in your second? Please [edit] your question to show **the** sample input and **the** expected output given that input plus what you've tried so far. Indent all 3 by 4 spaces so it's formatted properly.

Comment: When posting sample input, output, and/or code don't post an image and don't post a link - simply post text indented 4 spaces.

Comment: It was difficult to update as the view was being changed (to show) the exact response for the text, I have shared a link. Will also update the question as mentioned by you.

Comment: As stated a couple of times - you need to indent your text by 4 spaces to have appear as-is and you can use the editors `{}` button to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$ cat file
A
36
B
57
C
11

$ awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (NR%2 ? OFS : ORS)}' file
A 36
B 57
C 11
```

Comment: Hi Ed, this looks perfect works well, but due to some reason I can not stop mysql response to be like that instead I want to be to also transform pretty print to this simple response form can you help me do it ?

Comment: Probably but you didn't include that as textual input in your question so I don't have anything to test against. If you update your question to include that input/output I'll take another look.

Comment: Updating with text file

Comment: Don't post a link to text and don't post an image of text - simply post the actual text indented 4 spaces (you can use the editors `{}` button to do that for you).

Answer (score 1):

This [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)/[awk](/questions/tagged/awk)-filter [pipe](/questions/tagged/pipe) will unwrap your values from the pretty tables:

```
cat pretty-tables-dump.txt | 
sed 's/\xC2\xA0//g' |
awk '$1=="|"{if(f){print f" "$2;f=""}else{f=$2}}'
```

Edited to prepend stripping of UTF NBSP via `sed`.

Comment: Thanks alex, this is really helpful - I am new to shell especially text processing, can you share some link to learn and improve my skills with it ? or some path I should follow - just asking.

Comment: One question is after running the `sed 's/\xC2\xA0//g' | awk '$1=="|"{if(f){print f" "$2;f=""}else{f=$2}}'` the vm seems to be waiting for any other input - so I would have to interrupt using `cntrl+c`, How would I be able to do that in a shell/using command ?

Comment: @dynamicJos: My answer is a "bash shell pipeline filter expression using sed and awk". And *yes*, you need to feed it Input. For learning, just combine any unknown word in my answer/comment with "Howto", "Manual", "Introduction", "Examples", "Scripting",...  And then learn to love to read! A Lot! For a long time! Welcome to the JEDI cult ;)

Comment: I understand that, I have given a filename post the commands youve provided. I am just saying post hitting the command `sed 's/\xC2\xA0//g' | awk '$1=="|"{if(f){print f" "$2;f=""}else{f=$2}}' filename` - the output is generated as expected but the cursor is waiting for a `cntrl+c` to exit. How can I ensure the cursor jumps to bash once processing the input and displaying output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can  use `\G` instead of `;`for your mysql query .

Example :

```
information_schema]> select count(distinct table_schema) as CNT_SCHEMA from TABLES ;
+------------+
| CNT_SCHEMA |
+------------+
|          9 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

[information_schema]> select count(distinct table_schema) as CNT_SCHEMA from TABLES \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
CNT_SCHEMA: 9
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```